# Run NodeJs and Apache together with two separated domain

Tags: php, node.js, linux, apache, vps

I have a Linux server (VPS) with two domains and two web applications, one programmed with `NodeJS` (chat app) whereas the another is `PHP`.

So, what I want to do is running the two applications in separated domains on the same server. I've tried many methods to do this but all these methods working on single domain and multi URL path like : `https://example.com` & `https://example.com/node`.

But what I want is like this: `https://nodeappexample.com` & `https://apacheappexample.com`.

Greetings

Comment: You will need VirtualHosts, one per domain.  The problem you will run into, is since they are both https, you will have to use SNI (research on that) for your SSL portion.  If you cannot use SNI, you will have to use 1 IP per domain, for the SSL split between both domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on dedicated or VPS like DigitalOcean or any other server and planning to host multiple websites on a single server then here is how you can do it either with Apache HTTP or Nginx web server.

This assumes you have already mapped DNS to your host, like following two domains I have mapped to DigitalOcean.

```
bestflare.com
usefulread.com
```

Before you implement this, to give you an idea how it works. The concept to have multiple websites on a single instance is called Virtual Server. Virtual server configuration is defined within web server configuration and based on server/IP address, a request is getting forwarded to respective Document Root.

**Configure Virtual Host in Apache** to host multiple domains
Login into Apache HTTP Server
Go to apache conf location. ( in default installation – you will find it here /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf)
Take a backup of httpd.conf file
Create a VirtualHost container like below I have done for two domains.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin hello@chandank.com
   DocumentRoot /opt/htdocs/bestflare
   ServerName bestflare.com
   ErrorLog logs/bestflare.com-error_log
   CustomLog logs/bestflare.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin hello@chandank.com
   DocumentRoot /opt/htdocs/usefulread
   ServerName usefulread.com
   ErrorLog logs/usefulread.com-error_log
   CustomLog logs/usefulread.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: Change the value for ServerAdmin, DocumentRoot, ServerName, ErrorLog, CustomLog based on your requirement.

Restart Apache HTTP and test both urls.

**Configure Virtual Host in Nginx** to host multiple domains
Login into Nginx server
Go to virtual.conf location (in default location – you will find it here /etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf)
Take a backup of virtual.conf
Create server block for both URL’s as I have shown below.

```
server {
listen 80;
   root /opt/htdocs/bestflare;
index index.html index.htm;
   server_name bestflare.com;
   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
}
server {
   listen 80;
   root /opt/htdocs/usefulread;
   index index.html index.htm;
   server_name usefulread.com;
   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
}
```

Note: Change the value for root, server_name based on your requirement.

Restart Nginx and test both URL’s
That was the quick guide to hosting multiple domains in single web server instance like Apache or Nginx. Once your website is live, don’t forget to test it against security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to ask you some questions: `DocumentRoot` is the location of the application ? and what about NodeJS ?

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site
    ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost> // for document root

Comment: <VirtualHost node.example.com:80>   
    ServerName node.example.com  
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/ connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30  # optional timeout settings  
</VirtualHost> //You can use Proxy server for Nodejs

Comment: @MohammadRaheem I cannot found this file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` !! (working on debian 9)

Comment: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf --- Debian stores its Apache 2.0 configuration files in the directory /etc/apache2. Normally the main Apache configuration file is called httpd.conf.

Comment: I found this file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and there is no file called httpd.conf in `/etc/apache2/` so I created it then `Include` it into the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file, is that well ?

Comment: Everything is well now and all the virtual hosts which I've added is working well but the node app!, after using `ProxyPass / localhost:8000 connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30` it returns error when I try to reload apache server !