# Node.JS on GoDaddy cpanel not working

Tags: node.js, port

I have been trying to implement node.js in my website. I have been doing exactly what tutorials say. I successfully made it in local development. But when I implement it remotely, it doesn't work.

Here are my codes on cpanel:

app.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if(req.url === '/'){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/html');
        res.end('<strong>Sample text</strong>');
   }
});

server.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('Listening to port 8080');
});
```

When I run the command

```
node app.js
```

in Putty, it works. Showing the console log "Listening to port 8080".

But when I go to mydomain.com:8080, nothing appears. It says the site can't be reached.

Now is there any reason why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a way  to configure port with DNS , On which port your DNS server is running configure that port only, mostly Port 80 is used.

Comment: I tried changing the listening port to 80. But it throws an error in cli when turning on node.  Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80

Comment: You have to create Proxy or virtual server instance, you can see my answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49946381/run-nodejs-and-apache-together-with-two-separated-domain/49946789#49946789]

Answer (score 0):

### go to file manager in cpanel > (your domain) > public_html > .htaccess

edit to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:4100/$1 [P,L]
```

If use https

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f
# Add APIs here <--
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:4100/$1 [P,L]
```

If you have php APIs and want to redirect to it exactly just Add this line before the last line

```
RewriteRule ^api/info.php$ - [L,NC,R=301]
```

Make sure the port here is 4100 change it to 8080 in your case